# Проблема с вводом данных python

Tags: python, input

Имеем вот такой простой код

```py
hour = int(input())
minut = int(input())

hour *= 60
print(hour+minut)
```

Но при вводе данных выдается ошибка

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:''
```

Ошибка во второй строчке, пишу в PyCharm.

Comment: Говорят, это баг PyCharm. Включите в терминале PyCharm эмуляцию консоли.

Comment: Да, включил эмуляцию и все заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте следуйщий код:

```
hour = input()
minut = input()
#Преобразовываем строку в число
hour = int(hour)
minut = int(minut)
```

питон интерпретирует код как преобразовать функцию input() в число а не строку в число.

в данном коде переменные преобразовуются уже после превращения функции в строку а не перед

а от редактора кода здесь ничего не зависит.

Comment: Ваш код и код полностью аналогичен первым двум строкам кода в вопросе. Необходимости в таком разбиении на отдельные строки нет.

Comment: питон интерпретирует код по порядку: сначала он выполняет функцию int() и пытается преобразовать функцию input() в число, но так как функция input() ещё не выполнена, она остается функцией и питон не может её преобразовать в число. у меня была аналогичная проблема мне ето решение помогло

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь. Сначала выполняется input, потом int. Описанное вами возможно только если вы забыли добавить скобки к input, что-то типа `int(input)` вместо `int(input())`

Comment: возможно, я не уверен так как в пайчарме не работаю

Comment: Если была аналогичная проблема (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:''` на втором `int(input())`) - то см. ответ к вопросу, указанному как дубликат. Если была ошибка `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'`, то вы забыли добавить скобки к input. В любом случае, сам по себе код из вопроса вполне корректный.

Comment: спасибо но проблему я решыл

Comment: Возможно, только объяснение придумали неправильное

Comment: Все равно, решение не правильное, он считает что в переменной ```minut``` пустая строка, а не число, хотя я задую нормальные данные